# How to add a query to check if one of 2 strings contain the searched key

Tags: javascript, angular

My code looks something like this:

```
this.cashRegisterService
      .query({
        'storeName.contains': event.query,
        'identifier.contains': event.query,
      })
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.cashregisters = (data.body || []).map(cashRegister => ({
          id: cashRegister.id,
          name: `${cashRegister.identifier} ${cashRegister.storeName} (${cashRegister.mallName})`,
        }));
      });
```

I want to check if the identifier OR the storeName contain the event.query but what this does is to check if both of them contains the event.query. How can i do that? the method is generated by jhipster

```
query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get<ICashRegister[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
  }

export const createRequestOption = (req?: any): HttpParams => {
  let options: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

  if (req) {
    Object.keys(req).forEach(key => {
      if (key !== 'sort') {
        options = options.set(key, req[key]);
      }
    });

    if (req.sort) {
      req.sort.forEach((val: string) => {
        options = options.append('sort', val);
      });
    }
  }

  return options;
};
```

Comment: Your question is not related to jhipster